# return value that doesn't exist in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to do the following in mysql 5.5. The is_user column doesn't exist.

```
select name, is_user=>true from users;

name        is_user
joe         true
jane        true
```

How would I do this?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, 'true' AS is_user FROM users;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    name,
    true as `is_user`
from
    users;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fdcd/3

Comment: To date, yours is the only answer that supplies a Boolean value for the column "is_user".

Answer (score 0):

You can force a value this way:

```
select name, 'true' as is_user from users
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,
       'true' AS is_user
  FROM users
```

Quote [SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

> A `select_expr` can be given an alias using `AS alias_name`. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses.